# Cerrar procesos abiertos por mi propia aplicación VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Quisiera saber si existe alguna manera de cerrar procesos abiertos única y exclusivamente por mi aplicación. He visto mil maneras de cerrar procesos desde VB.NET, pero no logro encontrar la manera de localizar los que yo abro desde mi aplicación.

Estoy trabajando con la librería Interop de Excel y al principio del programa abro una instancia de `Excel.Application` para trabajar con ella. El problema que tengo es que en algunas ocasiones se pueden generar excepciones en la aplicación, ya sea porque un archivo al que se quiere acceder está abierto o cosas así. Estoy controlando esas excepciones, pero si la acción que estoy realizando abre un proceso (en mi caso siempre es un proceso EXCEL) y ocurre una excepción, me deja el proceso abierto.

Por poner un ejemplo, si durante la ejecución del programa suceden 4 excepciones que me dejan cada una un proceso EXCEL abierto, al cerrar el programa se me quedan los 4 procesos abiertos. Cuando todo va bien, siempre tengo un único proceso EXCEL abierto que se cierra correctamente cuando cierro la aplicación, pero cuando ocurren excepciones, no sé cómo cerrar solo los procesos EXCEL abiertos que me interesan. No sé si disponen de algún tipo de id al que pueda acceder o algo así para cerrar aquellos que me interesan (en este caso los que se quedan abiertos tras la excepción), ya que el proceso EXCEL principal no puedo cerrarlo si quiero que la aplicación siga funcionando correctamente.

No sé si me he podido explicar correctamente o si hacen falta más datos ya que no sé muy bien cómo expresar esta pregunta para que se me entienda bien lo que quiero decir.

Muchas gracias por lo que podáis indicarme y disculpas si algo no ha quedado del todo claro.

Saludos.

Comment: Cuando ocurre una excepcion perdes la referencia al proceso excel?

Comment: no tengo claro a qué te refieres con referencia. Cuando se crea el proceso, ¿es posible guardar alguna referencia o número que me permita matarlo después? De ser así, cuando esté creando las instancias y procesos excel me puedo guardar esas referencias y cuando cierre el programa identificarlas y matarlas. Lo cierto es que desconozco si se puede guardar alguna referencia de los procesos que abro.. =(